# Using Self-Signed Certificates with REST connector in Cloud Connect

Tags: gooddata, cloud-connect

I am working on integrating Cloud Connect with our platform's REST APIs.  I am receiving an error when trying to connect to our development servers using the REST connector:

```
Component [REST Connector:REST_CONNECTOR] finished with status ERROR.
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Our development environment uses a self-signed SSL certificate, which I suspect is at the heart of the issue.  How might I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that when running the graphs on GoodData servers, there is no way you could configure them to trust your self-signed certificates.

If you would be running the graph locally however (which should be OK for development), adding that certificates (or certification authority) to trusted certificates on your local machine should do the trick (and restarting CloudConnect after it, just to be sure it is reflected).